# Create up to 8 byte unique integer and still have parallel insert

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, insert, key, unique

During insert having a `Sequence` or `identity` or `row_number()` is causing the insert to be single threaded.

`NEWID()` can be multithreaded but that's 16 bytes. I am trying to create a unique up to 8 byte = 64 bit integer and still have parallel insert (SQL Server 2019 or Azure Managed Instance)

Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Is row_numbering getting batch mode, as then it should go parallel? See also https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/real-world-parallel-insert-select-what-else-you-need-to-know/ba-p/305329

Comment: You are right, I thought I tried this already but I was mistaken.

https://screenrec.com/share/AfkFQ0JzrM

Comment: That looks very parallel to me. Note the double arrows on the Insert, and the "Gather Streams" to the *left* of the Insert

Comment: To get batch mode you always need a CCI table in the query. If you want to force it on a rowstore table, you can do `left join MyEmptyCCITable on 1 = 0`, this will not affect semantics and will be elided by the compiler